# Markov processes on function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Is there any reference on Continuous time Markov process whose state space is infinite dimensional function spaces, such as the space of continuous functions $C(R^d)$?

It seems Dirichlet Form is a more natural way to do the construction, because the generator involves some kind of functional derivative whose domain is delicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A fundamental theorem of Fukushima says that a sufficient condition for a Dirichlet form to be associated to a Markov process is that it be *regular*: in particular, this condition requires the state space to be locally compact, and doesn't cover infinite dimensional state spaces.   However, Albeverio, Ma and Röckner have given a *necessary* and sufficient condition which they call *quasi-regular*, and it allows for state spaces which are not locally compact.

See:

> [MR1200639](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1200639) Albeverio, S., Ma, Z. M., Röckner, M. 
>   Quasi-regular Dirichlet forms and Markov processes.
>   *J. Funct. Anal.* **111** (1993), no. 1, 118–154.
>
> [MR1214375](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1214375)
>   Ma, Zhi Ming, Röckner, Michael.  *Introduction to the theory of (nonsymmetric) Dirichlet forms.*
>   Universitext. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1992. vi+209 pp. ISBN: 3-540-55848-9
>   60J40

Comment: Sweet Thanks a lot. I'm taking a closer look at your reference.